# Oracle VM CPU usage at 100% even if only 3 out of 4 cores assigned

Tags: scientific-linux, oracle-vm-server

I'm running a linux VM guest inside a Win10 host. I assigned 3 cpu cores to the VM (out of the 4 cores of my i7 6600K). When compiling some big software package I run make -j3 and then looked at the CPU usage in Win10 Task Manager it's pegged at > 95%. I was naively expecting something around 75 or 80%.
Anyone knows what's going on?

Screenshot:

[image: Here a screenshot of the problem]